# how to run two Java codes parallely using processes

Tags: java

Can anyone help me how to run two Java codes parallely using processes (not thread). For example,

```
class A{
method1()
}

class B{
method2()
}
```

I want to run mehod 1 & 2 parallely using two separate processes.

How to do that ?

Comment: Make two seperate programs? Why don't you want to use threads?

Comment: @Recursed, Because threads are not doing well for I/O blocking. I want to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open two command prompts and then,

```
javac A.java
java A
```

and then, In another command prompt

```
javac B.java
java B
```

EDIT: After comments

Please look into this tutorial.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8

@MadProgrammer's suggestion : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: There is no programmatic soln ?

Comment: @Arpssss Yes, it's called `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.lang.Runtime class' exec method or a ProcessBuilder class for the purpose of creating a new process programmatically.

Comment: +1 it is the natural way to do this job with mastering  JVM parameters